# Connecting a server to my android app

Tags: java, android, mobile, server

I am creating an android app in android studios that allows for users within a group (i.e. classroom, work environment etc...) to anonomously make suggestions to improve the environment or whatever it may be. I want it to be like a log such as Twitter or Instagram where it keeps the currently submitted suggestions.

I also have no server or anything so any feedback as to where to get started with that would help a lot.

My question is how do I get a server to let me keep a log of the already submitted suggestions (like Twitter and Instagram) and how to input new suggestions to this server and then let this new server send data back so it keeps like a log within the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood what you mean but I'll try to answer...
You should use restful API: http POST to send data to your server, http GET to retrieve data from server.
For example you post a log, the server saves your log in a db, than you call a get API passing last sync date as parameter so that the server return all new logs from that date timestamp